# Combining js with media queries ( viewport related )

Tags: javascript, media-queries, viewport

Recently I was asked (by a client) to use a js snippet to change meta viewport tags width based on resolution. They said it may increase the performance of the mobile/tablet version of the site. But I resist to believe it because in my mind it looks somewhat the same  as viewport tags    width=device-width, even worse I would say.

This is the snippet:

```
    function setviewport(){
         if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
              if(screen.height > screen.width){
                   deviceWidth = screen.width;
              }else{
                   deviceWidth = screen.height;
              }
         }else{
              if(screen.height > screen.width){
                   deviceWidth = screen.height;
              }else{
                   deviceWidth = screen.width;
              }
         }

         if(deviceWidth<=512){
              $("#viewport").attr("content","width=480,initial-scale="+deviceWidth/480);
         }else if(deviceWidth>=960){ 
              $("#viewport").attr("content","width=1024");
         }else{
              $("#viewport").attr("content","width=768,initial-scale="+deviceWidth/768);
         }
    }
```

Maybe I don't understand anyhthing and this is trully a better option that just width=device-width. And if it is, could you explain why is it? Does it increase performance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do that, if performance is your reason. You are altering some variables used by the clients throughout the rendering process. And you are doing so after the page was already (at least party) rendered and effectively repeating the rendering of the current page. Please be aware, that browser manufacturers are doing huge efforts to optimize the rendering performance and I doubt that a single client of yours is smarter than the whole Chrome or Firefox teams. If you still want to build something like that into your site, you should use scientific methods to measure the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your client is worried about performance gains with javascript over css media-queries to create responsive web design.

This can be attributed to a common **myth** among people that:

> browser must wait until it downloads, parses, and applies the relevant
> CSS before it can render the page on the screen.

Not respecting this might lead to a "flash of unstyled content" (FOUC), which would create a poor user experience. On the other hand Javascript can be loaded async and thereby not interfering with page-rendering.

**This is not true**. Modern rendering engines are much smarter than many of us give them credit for.

*However, It does matter how many different media queries you use on the site when you’re resizing the browser window.* This can cause a CPU and memory load which even can crash your browser *but this is not a valid performance test* (no user constantly resizes its browser, we should always focus on non-resizing events only).

Also, media-queries are not supported by some of the older browsers(IE-8 and previous) in that case you would like to make use of javascript library([respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)), but otherwise javascript have no upperhand in providing drastic *performance gains* over css media-queries.

**Source:**

- [responsive css performance myths](https://www.igvita.com/2012/06/14/debunking-responsive-css-performance-myths/)
- [web performance one-or-thousand media queries](https://helloanselm.com/2014/web-performance-one-or-thousand-media-queries/)

Comment: Thanks, just what i needed to get around this "myth"  !